# Require auto increment id value to be assigned when saving record

Tags: sequelize.js

I came across an strange error when saving a db record with `sequelize`. The errror is:

```
Error: DatabaseError: null value in column 'id' violates not-null constraint
```

The `id` field was created `serial` as auto increment and was not assigned a value before `save`. Here is the code:

```
order = Order.build(d);
           try {
               await order.save();
           } catch(error) {
               console.log('Order# ${d.platform_order_id} NOT saved.', error.message);
           };
```

My understanding is that I don't need to assign value to the `id` as the database is going to take care of it. Here is the `order-id-seq`:

[image]

What I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the definition model schema like below :-

**add autoIncrement: true in id filed**

```
id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    field: 'id',
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
}
```